# Get jsons value with js

Tags: javascript, json

I want to get the *"appid"* of [this](http://steamspy.com/api.php?request=top100in2weeks) json but the problem is that the objects title change during the time so I need a js code where the *"appid"* is selected by being the first (second, third) object in the list. I tried this but it doesn't work :(

```
var sections = (call the json)

var index = [];

//setting the index array
for (var x in sections) {
    index.push(x);
}

var imgid001 = (sections[index[1]].appid);
```

Comment: Try this `Object.values(json).map(({appid}) => appid)`

Comment: normally, what you have makes sense... Please what doesn't work? Include expected behaviour and current behavior...

Comment: The problem is that the sections appear in different order, for example the number that should appear in the first variable (_578080_), appears in the 90th variable (where should appear _475150_). Think that at the bottom I have only display one variable but there is 100 variables (one for each section in the JSON)

Comment: @Markel thank you, and why would you absolutely need 578080 to be the first just like in the JSON?

Comment: @Salketer Because if you see the JSON the first one is 578080

Comment: @Markel yes, but the JSON could put it in any order, that does not give any meaning... See my answer about that

Comment: @Markel `appid` contains the key value. You can access the key value directly using `Object.keys()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what are you looking for? 
But maybe this helps:

```
var sections = (al the json code in local)    
var index = [];    
//setting the index array
for (var x = 0 ; x < sections.lenght; x ++){
    index.push(x)
}    
var imgid001 = (sections[index[90]].appid);
```

Comment: crashes the program

Comment: `index.push(x)` is pushing the index of the loop, a number, into the index array, not the object and sections is an object not an array

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to access the values corresponding to a key and then use [`array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the `appid` value.

```js
var json = {"578080":{"appid":578080,"name":"PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS","developer":"PUBG Corporation","publisher":"PUBG Corporation","score_rank":17,"positive":277104,"negative":173247,"userscore":60,"owners":22512885,"owners_variance":142499,"players_forever":22385548,"players_forever_variance":142115,"players_2weeks":16894492,"players_2weeks_variance":124193,"average_forever":8570,"average_2weeks":1771,"median_forever":5509,"median_2weeks":1266,"price":"2999"},"730":{"appid":730,"name":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive","developer":"Valve","publisher":"Valve","score_rank":74,"positive":2094164,"negative":228950,"userscore":89,"owners":37137816,"owners_variance":180096,"players_forever":35672331,"players_forever_variance":176797,"players_2weeks":9605392,"players_2weeks_variance":94373,"average_forever":17518,"average_2weeks":714,"median_forever":4280,"median_2weeks":282,"price":"1499"},"570":{"appid":570,"name":"Dota 2","developer":"Valve","publisher":"Valve","score_rank":64,"positive":742208,"negative":101331,"userscore":87,"owners":117932840,"owners_variance":290445,"players_forever":117932840,"players_forever_variance":290445,"players_2weeks":9220909,"players_2weeks_variance":92502,"average_forever":11673,"average_2weeks":1144,"median_forever":258,"median_2weeks":640,"price":"0"}};

var result = Object.values(json).map(function(obj){ 
      return obj.appid;
    });
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can be display each one in different variables, example:
x=570
y=730
z=578080

Comment: It will return an array, you can assign different variable based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the problem you are facing is with the ordering of the elements... You'd want the game ranked number one be at index 1?

When parsing an object to JSON, the order of the properties have absolutely no meaning. You cannot rely on any JSON tool to make sure you'd get them in the right order either. In theory, just creating an object and passing it through a for..in loop could possibly give different results from time to time.

While it has no order, it still includes a way to figure it out the `score_rank`

```
var sections = (call the json)

var index = [];

//setting the index array
for (var x in sections) {
    index[sections[x].score_rank] = x;
}

var imgid001 = (sections[index[1]].appid);
```

Using score_rank as the index in your `index` map will get you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have an object here, not a list/array so the order is not guaranteed! There is no way of doing what you are planning using this format.

If you need ordering, you need the json to be an array.

```js
var sections = {"578080":{"appid":578080,"name":"PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS","developer":"PUBG Corporation","publisher":"PUBG Corporation","score_rank":17,"positive":277104,"negative":173247,"userscore":60,"owners":22512885,"owners_variance":142499,"players_forever":22385548,"players_forever_variance":142115,"players_2weeks":16894492,"players_2weeks_variance":124193,"average_forever":8570,"average_2weeks":1771,"median_forever":5509,"median_2weeks":1266,"price":"2999"},
  "730":{"appid":730,"name":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive","developer":"Valve","publisher":"Valve","score_rank":74,"positive":2094164,"negative":228950,"userscore":89,"owners":37137816,"owners_variance":180096,"players_forever":35672331,"players_forever_variance":176797,"players_2weeks":9605392,"players_2weeks_variance":94373,"average_forever":17518,"average_2weeks":714,"median_forever":4280,"median_2weeks":282,"price":"1499"},
  "570":{"appid":570,"name":"Dota 2","developer":"Valve","publisher":"Valve","score_rank":64,"positive":742208,"negative":101331,"userscore":87,"owners":117932840,"owners_variance":290445,"players_forever":117932840,"players_forever_variance":290445,"players_2weeks":9220909,"players_2weeks_variance":92502,"average_forever":11673,"average_2weeks":1144,"median_forever":258,"median_2weeks":640,"price":"0"},
  "440":{"appid":440,"name":"Team Fortress 2","developer":"Valve","publisher":"Valve","score_rank":85,"positive":456688,"negative":29364,"userscore":93,"owners":43830288,"owners_variance":194180,"players_forever":43830288,"players_forever_variance":194180,"players_2weeks":1690982,"players_2weeks_variance":39926,"average_forever":4490,"average_2weeks":655,"median_forever":226,"median_2weeks":381,"price":"0"},
  "271590":{"appid":271590,"name":"Grand Theft Auto V","developer":"Rockstar North","publisher":"Rockstar Games","score_rank":24,"positive":234736,"negative":112774,"userscore":67,"owners":8775849,"owners_variance":90285,"players_forever":8583731,"players_forever_variance":89309,"players_2weeks":1667493,"players_2weeks_variance":39648,"average_forever":7619,"average_2weeks":491,"median_forever":4032,"median_2weeks":160,"price":"5999"}};


var sectionsArray= [{"appid":578080,"name":"PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS","developer":"PUBG Corporation","publisher":"PUBG Corporation","score_rank":17,"positive":277104,"negative":173247,"userscore":60,"owners":22512885,"owners_variance":142499,"players_forever":22385548,"players_forever_variance":142115,"players_2weeks":16894492,"players_2weeks_variance":124193,"average_forever":8570,"average_2weeks":1771,"median_forever":5509,"median_2weeks":1266,"price":"2999"},
  {"appid":730,"name":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive","developer":"Valve","publisher":"Valve","score_rank":74,"positive":2094164,"negative":228950,"userscore":89,"owners":37137816,"owners_variance":180096,"players_forever":35672331,"players_forever_variance":176797,"players_2weeks":9605392,"players_2weeks_variance":94373,"average_forever":17518,"average_2weeks":714,"median_forever":4280,"median_2weeks":282,"price":"1499"},
  {"appid":570,"name":"Dota 2","developer":"Valve","publisher":"Valve","score_rank":64,"positive":742208,"negative":101331,"userscore":87,"owners":117932840,"owners_variance":290445,"players_forever":117932840,"players_forever_variance":290445,"players_2weeks":9220909,"players_2weeks_variance":92502,"average_forever":11673,"average_2weeks":1144,"median_forever":258,"median_2weeks":640,"price":"0"},
  {"appid":440,"name":"Team Fortress 2","developer":"Valve","publisher":"Valve","score_rank":85,"positive":456688,"negative":29364,"userscore":93,"owners":43830288,"owners_variance":194180,"players_forever":43830288,"players_forever_variance":194180,"players_2weeks":1690982,"players_2weeks_variance":39926,"average_forever":4490,"average_2weeks":655,"median_forever":226,"median_2weeks":381,"price":"0"},
  {"appid":271590,"name":"Grand Theft Auto V","developer":"Rockstar North","publisher":"Rockstar Games","score_rank":24,"positive":234736,"negative":112774,"userscore":67,"owners":8775849,"owners_variance":90285,"players_forever":8583731,"players_forever_variance":89309,"players_2weeks":1667493,"players_2weeks_variance":39648,"average_forever":7619,"average_2weeks":491,"median_forever":4032,"median_2weeks":160,"price":"5999"}];
    
    


for (var x in sections) {
    console.info("this will not be the first elements appid in json:", x);
    break;
}

console.info("Object keys/order", Object.keys(sections));

console.info("first element in array", sectionsArray[0].appid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
 var data = {"100":{appid:1, name:'1'}, "200":{appid:2, name:'2'}, "300":{appid:3, name:'3'}};

 var appIds = [];
 for (var property in data){
   appIds.push(data[property].appid);
 }

 console.log(appIds);
```

Based from your data, your property names are numbers with an object value. Hence, we just need to iterate to all the properties and access the value's appid property using obj[propertyname] syntax.

Hope I understood what you need.

Comment: properties are appids... So data[property].appid is redundent

Comment: the code above results is an array of appids e.g. [1,2,3]. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are iterating to an object’s properties, the order of the properties is not so predictable (in this case it seems to follow the numeric value of the main property string) so you cannot rely on it.

But, if it’s useful to your goal, you can sort your result by a property you choose.
In this case, I sort the result by the "score_rank" property:

```js
var sections = {
    "2":{"appid":"appidN1-scorerank5","name":"PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS","developer":"PUBG Corporation","publisher":"PUBG Corporation","score_rank":5,"positive":277104,"negative":173247,"userscore":60,"owners":22512885,"owners_variance":142499,"players_forever":22385548,"players_forever_variance":142115,"players_2weeks":16894492,"players_2weeks_variance":124193,"average_forever":8570,"average_2weeks":1771,"median_forever":5509,"median_2weeks":1266,"price":"2999"},
    "3":{"appid":"appidN2-scorerank2","name":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive","developer":"Valve","publisher":"Valve","score_rank":2,"positive":2094164,"negative":228950,"userscore":89,"owners":37137816,"owners_variance":180096,"players_forever":35672331,"players_forever_variance":176797,"players_2weeks":9605392,"players_2weeks_variance":94373,"average_forever":17518,"average_2weeks":714,"median_forever":4280,"median_2weeks":282,"price":"1499"},
    "4":{"appid":"appidN3-scorerank3","name":"Dota 2","developer":"Valve","publisher":"Valve","score_rank":3,"positive":742208,"negative":101331,"userscore":87,"owners":117932840,"owners_variance":290445,"players_forever":117932840,"players_forever_variance":290445,"players_2weeks":9220909,"players_2weeks_variance":92502,"average_forever":11673,"average_2weeks":1144,"median_forever":258,"median_2weeks":640,"price":"0"},
    "1":{"appid":"appidN4-scorerank4","name":"PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS","developer":"PUBG Corporation","publisher":"PUBG Corporation","score_rank":4,"positive":277104,"negative":173247,"userscore":60,"owners":22512885,"owners_variance":142499,"players_forever":22385548,"players_forever_variance":142115,"players_2weeks":16894492,"players_2weeks_variance":124193,"average_forever":8570,"average_2weeks":1771,"median_forever":5509,"median_2weeks":1266,"price":"2999"},
    "6":{"appid":"appidN5-scorerank1","name":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive","developer":"Valve","publisher":"Valve","score_rank":1,"positive":2094164,"negative":228950,"userscore":89,"owners":37137816,"owners_variance":180096,"players_forever":35672331,"players_forever_variance":176797,"players_2weeks":9605392,"players_2weeks_variance":94373,"average_forever":17518,"average_2weeks":714,"median_forever":4280,"median_2weeks":282,"price":"1499"},
    "5":{"appid":"appidN6-scorerank0","name":"Dota 2","developer":"Valve","publisher":"Valve","score_rank":0,"positive":742208,"negative":101331,"userscore":87,"owners":117932840,"owners_variance":290445,"players_forever":117932840,"players_forever_variance":290445,"players_2weeks":9220909,"players_2weeks_variance":92502,"average_forever":11673,"average_2weeks":1144,"median_forever":258,"median_2weeks":640,"price":"0"}
    
    }
    
    var result = Object.values(sections)
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.score_rank - b.score_rank;
    })
    .map(function(obj){ 
          
          return obj.appid;
        });
    
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
var sections = {a:9, b:8, c:7};

var index = [];

//setting the index array
for (var i in sections) { // sections['a','b','c']
    index.push(i);
}

alert(index[1]) // 'b'
alert(sections[index[1]]); // 8

// var sections = {a:9, b:{appid:5}, c:7};
// alert(sections[index[1]]); // firefox: {} or nothing (maybe)
// alert(sections[index[1]].toSource()); // firefox: {appid:5}
// alert(sections[index[1]].appid); // 5
```